# SQL way too slow in Android... how do I speed it up?

Tags: android, sql

I'm writing a keyboard app for android and I'm string key values in a SQL DB.

Here's an example row for one key. In the whole DB I have roughly 160 such rows.

```
(BTNID,TEXTADJUST,BUTTONSCALE,BUTTONSCALECNT,SPACINGLR,SPACINGTB,BTNOPA,BTNTEXT,BTNTEXTONCLICK,BTNTEXTONSHIFTCLICK,BTNTEXTCOLOR,BTNHUE,BTNSAT,LAYOUTSTDALTNUM,ATROW,BTNHUEHIT) VALUES('1','0','1','1','2','5','255','Q','qQ','Qq','0xFFFFFFFF','0','0','STD','1','0')
```

I'm reading this values by

```
TBL_NAME = preferences.getString("TBL", "EnglishZLayout");

        SqlHelper sqlHelper = new SqlHelper(this, "TK.db", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase DB = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        String TBL_NAME_BTN = TBL_NAME.replace("ZLayout", "ZButtons");
        Cursor c = DB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TBL_NAME_BTN, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
           ...
```

and strangely it takes about 20-30 seconds to load. Any ideas how to speed it up?

I can't store key values within the app, since the user has to be able to change them.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...something seems to be wrong. SQL usually never takes this long. What work is being done here?

Comment: Are you sure that it's (only) the query that takes so long? 20 seconds seems way beyond normal, even on the emulator… Have you tried (only) a very simple log output in your cursor loop, and testing this on a real device?

Comment: Well, it also draws the buttons in vector form, etc. but it doesn't take long, as I as when I am switching withing already loaded layout, they appear instantly.

Comment: I'm doing it on the real device, nexus S.

Comment: Yeap, appears that you're right. I had removed everything else from the loop and it fired in no time. :/ So will have to optimize the vector drawing part.

Answer (score 1):

You're not recreating the DB helper every time you execute the query, are you? Do this once on app startup.

Answer (score 0):

To turn my comment into an "answer" for anyone else who might find this post:

- Try the loop without the actual button drawing code... you'll likely see that the SQL is not the problem